# GitHub - no changes seen after successful commit

Tags: github, commit

I'm struggling with an issue connected to GitHub. I've committed some changes using GitBash console and got an info that the push was successful and there's nothing to commit. When I went into logs, there was this particular log looking like this:

[image: GitBash - git log]

The issue is that when I go back into my GitHub account, I can see just an initial commit in there, nothing more.

And the console clearly says that the commit was successful.

Please help!

Comment: You pushed to the wrong branch or wrong remote.

Comment: I have no other branch or remote to commit to, and the fact is when I check the status, everyting in the github branch (both master and trunk) is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a distributed version control system, so you have one local *copy* of the repository, Github has another copy. As far as git is concerned every copy is equally important.

For your changes to exist in Github, you have to `push` them there, with something like:

```
git push origin master
```

Try `git remote -v` to get more information on your tracked repositories.  Github has some great [help pages](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) on this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For what you say in your question, I think you don't have actually pulled your local repository in your GitHub account.
To do that, use `git push origin master` 
When you use `git commit` your changes are saved in your local repository, not in your remote (that in this case is GitHub)

Comment: Thanks for your answerr. I actually did the add, commit and push origin trunk. And it did all the work, but still cannot see the results on my GitHub account.

Comment: Have you tried git push origin master instead of git push origin trunk?

Comment: I did, but I get the info that there's nothing to commit. And everything is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that helped me understand my issue. Turns out the files did not copy between folders properly and that's why there're not changes detected on git. Now everything is working.

Thanks again!